# }Else{ statement not reading boolean?

Tags: php

So I've been working with php again, and I've set a variable to false, however, no matter what I do, when it gets to the IF statement, it echos the TRUE version when it should be echoing the FALSE version.

```
    $loginauth= $_POST['loginauth'];
    $errormain = false; // I've clearly set $errormain to false

if(!empty($loginauth)){
    if(!empty($username)){
        if(!empty($pass)){

        }else{$errormain = false;}// In an effort to fix this issue, I've set each one 
        }else{$errormain = true;}// of these $errormain = true; statements to false
        }else{$errormain = true;}// systematically one by one, yet somehow it still echos as if it was true.

  if($errormain = true){
      $errormain1 = "<h1>Error</h1><em>Login Failed</em>";
  }else{
      $errormain1 = "<h1>Welcome</h1><em>BadgesCoding.com</em>";
  }
```

Comment: You're assigning with `if($errormain = true){` instead of comparing `if($errormain == true){`

Comment: Do you understand comparison vs assignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `=` you are assigning value. Thus by this logic `$errormain` will always be `true`:

```
if ($errormain = true) {
```

It should be this using `==` for a true comparison test:

```
if ($errormain == true) {
```

Now if you set it to `===` then it will evaluate `$errormain` as `true` but also ensure the variable type is the same:

```
if ($errormain === true) {
```

But you know what? Make your life easier & just do this:

```
if ($errormain) {
```

You know why? That simple logic on the last line basically checks if `$errormain` is `true` without having to be redundant with the `== true` or `=== true`.

Comment: @RPM That's what I'm asking myself.

Comment: because the initial answer was wrong. you should never use `==` to compare boolean values to an expected boolean. only in situations where type isn't important should you use `==`

Comment: It's not wrong, I would say that it may cause unpredictable behavior. `1 == 1` will be true, as well as `true == true`. It is not required to use the `===`

Comment: @RPM `1==true` `'string' == true` `@ == true` `php_info() == true` so on and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit(for correctness and removing of badhabits)**

There is no need for the `$errormain` variable at all. logically, if `$loginauth`,`$username`,or`$password` are empty then error is true. therefore a better, but still flawed version of your code is as follows.

```
$loginauth= $_POST['loginauth'];
if(!empty($loginauth) && !empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
    //perform extra validation here please.
    $errormain1 = "<h1>Welcome</h1><em>BadgesCoding.com</em>";
}else{
    $errormain1 = "<h1>Error</h1><em>Login Failed</em>";
}
```

**Previous Answer below(left for the valuable wisdom the answer contains)**
You are using the wrong comparison operator. to compare boolean values correctly you have to use the `===` operator, so:
do not use `==` to compare boolean values either. it does not type juggle, meaning it basically doesn't insure the two comparisons are the same type, meaning 1 could be equal to true or any string value could be as well. 0 would be equal to false.

your code should look something like this:

`if($errormain === true){`

|| (or)

`if($errormain){`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to compare you must use == operator... the other thing i've seen is that you have an **$errormain** variable set to false... why? if password is empty **$errormain** must be true... i put a comment, take a look at it and change variable to true if you think it's correct. here's the code:

```
$loginauth = $_POST['loginauth'];
$errormain = false; // I've clearly set $errormain to false

if(!empty($loginauth)){
    if(!empty($username)){
        if(!empty($pass)){
            //pass is not empty
        }
        else{
            $errormain = false;//WHY IS THIS SET TO FALSE? if password is empty errormain must be false or true?
        }// In an effort to fix this issue, I've set each one 
    }
    else{
        $errormain = true;
    }// of these $errormain = true; statements to false
}
else{
    $errormain = true;
}// systematically one by one, yet somehow it still echos as if it was true.

if($errormain == true){
    $errormain1 = "<h1>Error</h1><em>Login Failed</em>";
}
else{
    $errormain1 = "<h1>Welcome</h1><em>BadgesCoding.com</em>";
}
```

Comment: I must quote myself so I don't seem like a douche;
'Thank you @JakeGould Another reason it was echoing as it was "true" even if it was false was the order I put the }else{ statements in.' 

That's actually what I meant, I realized that mistake directly after Jake solving that issue for me. Thanks for pointing that out though. :) I realized the way the if statements went when it kept giving me the same error. Thank you for your help though!